# Restriction of a Specht module to the alternating group

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and denote by $S_n$ the symmetric group on $n$ letters. For $\lambda\vdash n$ a partition of $n$ the  Specht module $S^\lambda$ defines an irreducible representation. What happens, when such a module is restricted to the alternating group $A_n$?

Comment: There's a good answer to this in Fulton and Harris, "Representation Theory" section 5.1.